# Windows 7 failed to start

Tags: windows-7

I recently installed a windows 10, my pc was currently windows 7 so I decided to upgrade it. I took the windows 10 installation online and I had to fix in order for it to work. It worked and I had to wait for few hours for it to work and now when it's all finished my windows started showing up "windows failed to start a recent hardware or software change might be the cause". Please how can I fix this?!

Comment: On a different computer, download the Windows 10 ISO from the Media Creation Link and make a bootable USB key. Try to restart the above computer with this key and see if you can install Windows 10 that way.

Comment: So you upgraded your Windows 7 installation, but are bieng told the upgrade failed, what did you "fix" in order to get it to work exactly?